# Passing uiOutput between nested modules

Tags: r, module, shiny

In my app, I have two modules (nested) for which I want to pass uiOuput. In the example below, the output named "screen1" (created in the outer module)has to be passed to the inner module where it will be displayed. But It doesn't work..
Passing such uiOutput work from the original shinyApp to one module but I can't make it works between two modules.

```
innerUI <- function(id){
ns <- NS(id)

tagList(
  h4("Inner module"),
  uiOutput(ns('displayScreens'))
  )
}



inner <- function(input, output, session, params){

    output$displayScreens <- renderUI({
        params()
 })
}


outerUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  innerUI(ns('test1'))
}

outer <- function(input, output, session){

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    test = uiOutput("screen1")
  )

  callModule(inner, 'test1', params= reactive({rv$test}))


  output$screen1 <- renderUI({
    h4("I am the screen 1 !")
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  outerUI('test2')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(outer, 'test2')
    }

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be one with namespaces. You are creating `uiOutput("screen1")` in outer and passing it to inner without a namespace. You could pass the `uiOutput("screen1")` in a reactive like this:

```
test <- reactive({
  ns <- session$ns
  uiOutput(ns("screen1"))
})

callModule(inner, 'test1', params=test)
```

This should work.